# How do I call and trap/check the result something returns in Java?

Tags: java

Heres what I need to do. I need to ask the user for a Parcel Number. It'll then search through the array to find the Parcel Number. If the Parcel Number does not exist then it needs to show an error. Otherwise, if it does exist it then needs to prompt the user to enter a Parcel Width & Height.

Heres my code for this:

```
private static void selectSatchel() {
    System.out.println("Select Satchel Feature");
    System.out.println();

    // code for Stage 2 Requirement D) should go in here
    System.out.println();

    //temp reference for failed search
    Parcel temp = null;

    System.out.print("Enter Parcel Number: ");
    String parcelNumber = sc.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < parcelCount; i++) {

        if(parcels[i].getparcelNumber().equals(parcelNumber)) {

            temp = parcels[i];

        }

    }
    if(temp == null) {

        System.out.println("Parcel Number: " + parcelNumber + "not found!");
    }
    else {

        System.out.print("Enter Satchel Width: ");
        int parcelLength = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Satchel Height: ");
        int parcelWidth = sc.nextInt();
```

After the user has entered the Width & Height it should attempt to call the selectSatchel() method for the matching Parcel object and trap / check the result it returns.

This is my selectSatchel() method from another class:

```
public int selectSatchel(int parcelLength, int parcelWidth) {

    if(satchelSize != null) 
        return -1;

    if(parcelLength > 500 || parcelWidth > 400)

        return 0;

    else {

    //code for finding out smallest parcel size it will fit in  
    return calculatePostageCost();

    }
}
```

If the result returned by the call to the selectSatchel() method was -1 then the feature should display an error message stating that "a satchel size has already been selected for the parcel".

If the result returned by the call to the selectSatchel() method was zero (0) then the feature should display an error message stating that "the parcel dimensions are too large to deliver in a satchel".

Otherwise if either of the two above conditions are not met then the feature should proceed to display the value returned by the selectSatchel() method as the postage cost for the parcel.

So my question here is how do I trap an object and check the result it returns? Im a bit lost from this point.

Comment: try using booleans. Global variable boolean such as `oversized`

Comment: You could return `null` from the search method or throw an exception.  In either case you can manage the result and take appropriate action accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a control over what that `selectSatchel()` method returns. If so I would suggest you use an enum for this purpose. Then you can use a switch statement to do whatever the processing based on the results it returns. A skeleton code would be like this.

```
public enum SomeStatus {
    STATUS_ONE,
    STATUS_TWO,
    // ...
}
```

Then inside your caller method

```
switch (responseState) {
        case STATUS_ONE:
            // Do something here
        case STATUS_TWO:
            // Do something here
        default:
            // Default action should go here
}
```